# Visual Studio Code Language Extension Inherit Existing

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In Visual Studio Code it is relatively easy to add your own Language Extension just by providing a grammar file, e.g. via JSON.

I want to provide a syntax file for a particular script language I use. The script language is embedded in ARM Assembly source code, which there already exists a plugin for. So I basically want to extend the ARM Extension by my script language. Is that currently possible?

This would IMO be the way to go in my case, because if I just copy the existing extension (Which is MIT licenced) I would de-facto create a hard-fork, which I do not intend to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### 1. Injection

You can inject your language extension to the scope of the parent scope by adding the following to your `package.json`:

```
"contributes": {
    "grammars": [
        {
            "scopeName": "source.asm.x86_64.your_syntax_extension",
            "path": "./syntaxes/your_syntax_extension.json",
            "injectTo": [ "source.asm.x86_64" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

### 2. Include

If your language extension uses a custom file-type or you want to override some of the parent scope's syntax definitions, you can write you own definition and include the parent scope. You can use either of the following formats:

#### your_syntax_extension.json

```
{
  "fileTypes": [
    "myExtension"
  ],
  "name": "Your Syntax Extension",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "include": "source.asm.x86_64"
    }
  ],
  "scopeName": "source.asm.x86_64.your_syntax_extension"
}
```

#### your_syntax_extension.tmLanguage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>fileTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>myExtension</string>
    </array>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Your Syntax Extension</string>
    <key>patterns</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>include</key>
            <string>source.asm.x86_64</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>scopeName</key>
    <string>source.asm.x86_64.your_syntax_extension</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

In both cases, you might want to include the extended package as a dependency. To do so, add its unique identifier to your `package.json`:

```
"extensionDependencies": [
    "13xforever.language-x86-64-assembly"
]
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation, I'd like to add that I had to add `    "injectionSelector": "L:source",` to my grammar configuration JSON, in order for the injection to work. I also added a dependency to another extension, but at least in the dev host VS Code seemed to ignore it. Will that constraint be enforced only if the extension is published to the store or installed to the non-dev host?

In any case, I accepted your answer, because that's definitely the way to go.

Comment: I added an `extensionDependencies`  to a package that has none and VSCode did not install it. However, I can assure you it works for my published packages.